# Is it possible to render a page programmatically via url?

Tags: programming

I am interested in rendering a page programmatically via URL so that it is stored in the cache...

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide a LOT more information. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: There is a german blog article, maybe it helps, there are a few code fragments between to generate URLs and use curl to ping them all: http://www.webguys.de/magento/adventskalender/turchen-08-magento-cache-warming-und-weitere-caching-tricks/

Comment: Isn't this function best performed by https://www.varnish-cache.org/ or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the command-line you can use wget or curl to load the page. (Given the fact that the page is accessible via a url)

```
wget http://domain.com/page/that/you/want/to/load.html?really
```

OR

```
curl  http://domain.com/page/that/you/want/to/load.html?really >/dev/null 2>&1
```

As mentioned in the comments you still need to provide more information. My only guess would be that you are writing some kind of cache-warmer applications that loads several pages to store them in the cache?

**EDIT:** [Here](http://bit.ly/YwAOhS) is a nice little web based application (PHP) that I wrote in the past that does what you need.

Comment: I would post that link up on Github or someplace else reputable to review the code before downloading and unpacking a random tar.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a link to a new Github repo.